# Is there a way to keep the walls from coming back in the Mine area?

Tags: fez

In the mine area of Fez, when you blow up a wall it just comes back.

I have no idea what to do. Is there a way to keep the walls from coming back?

Answer (score 12):

The broken wall won't regenerate if you destroy the section completely. When the explosion chain appears to reach the end, wrap the screen until the full length of broken wall is obliterated.

Answer (score 2):

Keep turning the room, following the exploding wall until it reaches the end.